# Need help for a Vue - BMI Calculator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am learning Webdev with Vue. And in my project, I built a component to calculate the BMI of a person. I have created a form with `bootstrap-vue` to get the values I need. And now I need help for the JavaScript part. I just don't know how to correct it.

```html
<template>
  <div class="bmi-calc">

      <b-card title="BMI Calculator" img-src="https://picsum.photos/600/300/?image=25" img-alt="Image" img-top tag="article" style="max-width: 20rem;" class="mb-2">

        <b-form @submit="onSubmit" v-if="show">
            <!-- Height -->
            <b-form-group id="input-group-height" label="height" label-for="input-height" description="Height in cm">
                <b-form-input id="input-height" v-model="form.height" type="height"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>
            <!-- Weight -->
            <b-form-group id="input-group-weight" label="weight" label-for="input-weight" description="Weight in kg">
                <b-form-input id="input-weight" v-model="form.weight" type="weight"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>
        </b-form>

        <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
        <div>Solution is: <strong>{{ solution }}</strong></div>

        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      form: {
        height: '',
        weight: ''
      },
      show: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      var solution = null
      solution = this.weight / (this.height) ^ 2
    },
    onReset (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      // Reset our form values
      this.form.height = ''
      this.form.weight = ''
      // Trick to reset/clear native browser form validation state
      this.show = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.show = true
      })
    },
  }
}

</script>
```

Formula I have used: [image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues:

1. The *Submit*-button should be inside the form in order to trigger a`submit`-event properly:

```html
<b-form>
  <b-form-group>...</b-form-group>

  <b-button type="submit">Submit</b-button>
</b-form>
```

2. The template refers to `solution`, but that's only a local variable inside `onSubmit()`. To make that available for rendering, initialize it as a prop from `data()`, as shown below. You'll later set it in `onSubmit()` by using `this.solution = /* new value */`.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //...
      solution: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

3. `onSubmit()` refers to `this.weight` and `this.height`, but those values are actually stored under `this.form`, so they should be `this.form.weight` and `this.form.height`, respectively.
4. The BMI calculation is not using the correct syntax to square a number. You could either use [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow), or just multiply it with itself:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.solution = this.form.weight / Math.pow(this.form.height, 2)
      // OR
      this.solution = this.form.weight / (this.form.height * this.form.height)
    }
  }
}
```

5. The `<b-form-input>`s are bound to `form.height` and `form.weight`, but those are currently strings, which will result in an error in the BMI calculation, which requires numbers. Currently, the input types are incorrectly set to `type="height"` and `type="weight"`, but those should be `type="number"`. Also, when using `v-model` for a number, make sure to use the [`.number` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) so that the value is updated to the correct type:

```html
<b-form-input v-model.number="form.weight" type="number">
<b-form-input v-model.number="form.height" type="number">
```

[image: Edit Binding to number inputs]

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! But do you know how I can enter the weight as a float? At the moment it gives me a way to small number so i just multiplied everything by 10000 to get e right value.